# what is the replacement for htaccess files for Azure Web App with PHP>= 8 which now uses nginx?

Tags: nginx, azure-web-apps

We are using azure web apps to host a few static HTML pages, which cannot be hosted in Azure Static Web Apps because Azure static Web apps do not support uploading your own certificate.

Now we have our html pages on azure web apps, we need to create rewrite rules, so that depending on the domain, or headers etc, we can route to the right page.

How can this be done without the equivalent of htaccess files?

I have been told that the only solution is to downgrade to web apps with php 7 or below. This is not an issue, as we have no php on the site, but might be an issue because MS are planning to remove this hosting.

It seems odd if there is no way to do any kind of rewrite rules or modify the web server config with azure web app hosting.

Answer (score 1):

`.haccess` is solely Apache HTTPD feature, not connected to PHP in any way. With Apache and absolutely any version of PHP (or whatever you have) you'd be able to use .htaccess; without Apache you won't be able to use it.

[Apache's documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html) **never recommended** to use this feature, leaving only a single valid use case for it — a shared hosting where the tenant is unable to change `httpd.conf` file. If you have VPS or any other form of a personal server you should never use `.htaccess` even with Apache HTTPD, putting everything into `httpd.conf` instead (or into files explicitly included from there).

> You should avoid using `.htaccess` files completely if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using `.htaccess` files slows down your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a `.htaccess` file is better set in a `Directory` block, as it will have the same effect with better performance.

Most probably you should have gotten rid of this bad habit of using `.htaccess` files a long, long time ago.

Nginx is another HTTP server, and there is no analogous feature comparable to `.htaccess`. You always configure everything into the server configuration file, `nginx.conf` and into files explicitly included from it.

It is possible to translate Apache's rewrite rules into Nginx's rules. We can help you with that, but you need to show these rules.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am fairly fluent in apache and nginx conf.  The big win for htaccess is that I can code the rules in files in git along side the html, so that the deployment pipelines deploy the rules and pages at the same time, and no matter what apache server you use locally or for testing the rules will be there, its like a yaml build file.  The issues is that there is no where to put the nginx rules, as they are not part of our html, and the azure piplines which come with the azure web app only deploy to wwwroot.   Azure manages the nginx config, I dont know how it could be hacked

Comment: As nginx is an azure managed resource, e.g. if you add a new custom domain or certificate, it must be editing the webserver config internally, so any attempt to hack or modify the nginx config would get overwritten best case.  The crux is without something like htaccess files, the nginx config cant be extended we assume

Comment: Well, in that case your question simply happens to be off topic here. Questions involving web hosting control panels are off-topic because they [customize their systems so that standard system administration methods no longer apply](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8055). (Standard administration methods include installing appropriate software, directly editing its configuration files, building structures involving reverse proxies, application servers and so on, which is precisely what you are unable to do.)

Answer (score 1):

> It seems odd if there is no way to do any kind of rewrite rules or modify the web server config with azure web app hosting.

This isn't true, although the UX of it all is atrocious. However, the following process is straightforward and much preferred over your Cloudflare solution.

I'll give you an answer using a solution that I just put in place for my PHP 8.2 project.

1. I added a `default.conf` file to the root of our source control.

   a. This `default.conf` was created using the `default` nginx configuration file that is installed on the App Service. This default configuration file is found at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`.

   b. I edited the `default.conf` file in source control to include my nginx rewrite rules.
2. Deployment copies our source control repository to the Azure App Service's wwwroot directory including this `default.conf` file.
3. In the App Service > Configurations > General Settings, you need to add this small startup script to copy the `default.conf` file onto the one used by nginx

```
cp /home/site/wwwroot/default.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default; service nginx restart
```

Our `default.conf` file looks like this as a reference:

```
server {
    #proxy_cache cache;
    #proxy_cache_valid 200 1s;
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    root /home/site/wwwroot;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;
    port_in_redirect off;

    location / {
        index  index.php index.html index.htm hostingstart.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; #### this specifically was the rewrite rule we needed for our project
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /html/;
    }

    # deny access to .env files
    location = /.env {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }

    location = /.env.example {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }

    # Disable .git directory
    location ~ /\.git {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # Add locations of phpmyadmin here.
    location ~* [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.[Pp][Hh][Pp])(|/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout         300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout           3600;
        fastcgi_read_timeout           3600;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution to the issue that you cant add rewrite rules on Azure Web Service (without hacking startup scripts, hacking files and potentially breaking azure control panel functionality like adding new domains and certs)

That solution is to do put the free version of Cloudflare infront of Azure web apps, and use cloud flare rewrite rules (10 for free).  This solved our problems, although we would have preferred to have the rules in git deployed with our web app (which can be done with azure static web apps and azure web apps with php < 8).